# Combine 3 strings into one

Tags: php

I've been trying to combine 3 strings into one and having trouble doing so.

the strings are below.

```
$from="/2/3/4/5/6/";
$to="/30/31/32/33/34/";
$sub="/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/";#this is dynamic, ever changing past > (/2/3/4/5/6/)
```

the output must look like this below.

```
$output="/30/31/32/33/34/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/";
```

else if `$sub` changes like below then.

```
$from="/2/3/4/5/6/";
$to="/30/31/32/33/34/";
$sub="/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/";
$output="/30/31/32/33/34/6/7/8/";
```

and else if `$to` changes then this.

```
$from="/2/3/4/5/6/";
$to="/30/31/";
$sub="/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/";
$output="/30/31/6/7/8/";
```

the `$to` needs to be first, then the `$sub` at the end, minus the `$from` before the end `/*/(eg./6/)` to be combined into 1 string.

how is this possible?

Comment: If the seperator is always a `/` you can simply split the strings and then generate from the 3 resulting arrays the string you like.

Comment: What if $from="/2/3/4/5/6/", $to="/30/31/32/33/34/", and $sub="/2/3/4/5/7/8/" (note: no 6)? Do you want the output to be "/2/3/4/5/7/8/"? Or perhaps "/30/31/32/33/34/7/8/"? Or something else?

Comment: @hvd-> if $from="/2/3/4/5/6/", $to="/30/31/32/33/34/", and $sub="/2/3/4/6/5/7/8/" the output will be output="/30/31/32/33/34/6/5/7/8/" including the last /6/ like if $from="/2/3/4/" output will be $output="/30/31/32/33/34/4/6/5/7/8/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically storing array structures serialized inside strings. Clever [Exploding](http://php.net/explode) should help:

```
$output = $to
  . implode('/', array_diff(
      explode('/', $sub),
      array_slice(explode('/', $from), 0, -2)
    )) . '/';
```

An alternative could be regular expressions

Comment: That won't result in the desired output.

Comment: @knittl> if I use str_replace, how would I exclude the last /*/ from the $from? eg. if $from="/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/"; how do I make $from look like this $from="/2/3/4/5/6/7/";? to be able to put into that str_replace?

Comment: @knittl> I tried your new code, though the output wasnt right, when I used $from="/2/3/4/"; $to="/20/21/22/"; $sub="/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/"; the output was '/20/21/22/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9' it had include the /2/3/ when it should be excluded, and it deletes the end /, the output should of been '/20/21/22/4/5/6/7/8/9/' though I see what you mean about the str_replace, just have to exclude the $from before the end /*/

Comment: @1Rabbit: using arrays I get exactly the output you described → http://codepad.org/H80IGZY4

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get what you are looking for:

```
$str1 = substr($from, -2);
$pos = strpos($sub,$str1);
$str2 = substr($sub,$pos);
$output = $to.$str2;
```